# C# добавление логики деструктора в статический класс

Tags: c#, потоки-данных

Есть статический класс для работы с файлом. На время работы программы, ни кто кроме этого класса не "захочет" получать доступ к файлу. Т.к записывать данные в файл придётся часто(очень), то не сильно хочется открывать поток каждый раз, когда внешний код просит записать данные. В итоге пришёл к решению, создать SreamWriter при загрузке приложения, и "освободить" файл, при выгрузке, но столкнулся с проблемой отсутствия у статического класса деструктора. Собственно вопрос, как обойти эту проблему(за исключением пересмотра архитектуры класса, я понимаю, что если поменять статик класс на синглтон, то проблема решится сама собой, мне интересен выход именно из такой ситуации).

Одно из решений, которые приходят в голову, это подписаться на выгрузку домена, и так уже освободить файл, но может есть куда более элегантные решения?

Comment: Вот вы и обожглись со статикой. Статика - зло! Она не предназначена для таких целей! Делайте полноценный класс и используйте его, все, точка. Ну либо делайте очень дикие костыли по типу статичного SreamWriter, который вы когда надо закрывать вызовом метода или напрямую, но это полный бред!

Comment: Статика это не ООП. И без синглтона можно обойтись вполне; вы сами что-ли не можете проконтролировать сколько экземпляров этого класса будет инстанцировано?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, знаю, что ручной вызов местного "Finilaze", звучит адово, поэтому и ищу филигранные решения). Знаю что зло, просто в голову пришла такая идея, и так, ради спортивного интереса решил поискать, можно ли как то красиво решить такую задачу

Comment: @Bulson, про синглтон было сказано лишь по тому, что он спокойно решает мою проблему с "отсутствием у статического класса деструктора". И естественно я могу всё отследить, прочитайте мой предыдущий комментарий, надеюсь он внесёт ясности

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, прошу прощения,поправка - такую задачу, именно в этих условиях, без пересмотра архитектуры класса

Comment: Создавайте `SreamWriter` в классе-клиенте вашего статического утилитного класса, а затем его экземпляр передавайте в статический метод писателя аргуменом. Но это все дичь.

Comment: Знаете как красиво? IoC. Сделали себе класс, закинули его в контейнер, пометили как синглтон (если нужен 1 экземпляр) и все, дальше где он вам нужен просто в конструкторе его принимаете и используете, вот это красиво. А статика - это не красиво, это ужас, который годится разве что для утилит, расширений, не более. Сейчас у вас статичный объект, который живет всю жизнь вашего приложения, сами тогда закрывайте что надо у этого объекта, сами контролируйте его, лучше, синглтоном, да. Описанным вами вариантом (без синглтона) - бред.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, выносите в ответ ваш последний комментарий, звучит как правда.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Когда вы делаете объект статичным, это означает, что он будет жить считай все время, пока работает ваша программа и это может сыграть злую шутку.

Многие из за лени или незнания делают все статичным, потому что легче что, `MyClass.MyMethod();` или `var myClass = new MyClass(); myClass.MyMethod();`, первое, верно? А как потом из одного класса в другой передать значение? Тоже вопрос у многих и человеку проще сделать "глобальное" значение, которое будет легко доставать из любой точки приложения, но... через некое время они попадают на такие грабли, как у вас, ведь `static` "вечен")

В вашем случае вы можете сделать 2 вещи:

1. Передавать `Stream` в нужное место и использовать его там по назначению (например сделайте его публичным `static` и обращайтесь к нему напрямую, либо `public static SreamWriter SomeMethod(){...}`.
2. Сделать приватный статичный экземпляр в вашем классе, но наружу выдавайте органы управления, некие методы открытия/закрытия.

Другими словами, вы должны сами контролировать жизнь `SreamWriter`, но все это простите, бред и костыли и я не советую даже думать про такое. Лучше сделайте обычный класс, реализуйте ему `IDisposable` и используйте как положено.

Если вам нужно удобство, вам лень постоянно писать `var myClass = new MyClass();`, то я советую начать использовать IoC контейнеры, где достаточно всего раз поместить тип/объект в контейнер и уже дальше он сам будет следить за его жизнедеятельностью, вам достаточно попросить его в конструкторе нужного класса (DI).

Comment: Кстати спасибо про рассказ про IoC, слышал о таком, даже пользовался немного при работе с ASP.NET, но не вдавался в подробности, думаю, возьму на вооружение, спасибо

Answer (score 1):

> В итоге пришёл к решению, создать SreamWriter при загрузке приложения, и "освободить" файл, при выгрузке, но столкнулся с проблемой отсутствия у статического класса деструктора.

В принципе это и так будет более-менее работать, кроме того, что хвост может остаться незаписанным на диск. Простейший вариант - вместо деструктора явно вызывать некий метод перед завершением приложения, но тут есть нюанс - приложение может не только завершаться корректно, но и падать или зависать. Чтобы даже в таких ситуациях сохранить как можно больше данных, можно их сбрасывать на диск после каждой записи - для этого предназначен метод `Flush`, который (если я ничего не путаю) надо вызвать сначала на StreamWriter'е, а потом на Stream'е. Ещё есть вариант настроить StreamWriter так, чтобы он не использовал собственный буфер.